# Video editing with python or command line

Tags: python, command-line, fadein, fadeout, video-editing

I need to perform the following operations in my python+django project:

- joining videos with same size and bitrate
- joining videos and images (for the image manipulation I'll use PIL: writing text to an existing image)
- fading in the transitions between videos

I already know of some video editing libraries for python: [MLT framework](http://www.mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/) (too complex for my needs), [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) and [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/) (don't include all the features I want), [gstreamer bindings](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/bindings/) (terrible documentation).

I could also do all the work from command line, using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/), [mencoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder) or [transcode](http://www.transcoding.org/).

What's the best approach to do such a thing on a Linux machine.

EDIT: eventually I've chosen to work with melt (mlt's command line)

Answer (score 0):

http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page is a scripting language for video.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I forgot to mention I need it on a Linux server. Or if you mean this version of avisynth http://avisynth3.unite-video.com/download.html then it's not usable yet.

Comment: Sorry, it never occurred to me that avisynth was windows only

Answer (score 0):

Because ffmpeg is available on GNU/Linux, i thing using it with modules such as [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) or [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) is the best solution....

Comment: I'm using ffmpeg right now, but it's kind of difficult (or impossible?) adding effects like fade in and fade out, overlaying images and stuff like that. Or all this is possible and easy to do?

Comment: That's right: it seems impossible to make fade-in/fade-out with ffmpeg...  Alternatively, maybe this link will help you: http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmsuper8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV for joining videos and images.  See the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/), in particular the [image/video I/O functions](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html).

However, I'm not sure if the library has functions that will do the fading for you.

Comment: If it could join, couldn't you just join a "fade" video with your current one? Or I guess the joins are just hard cuts?

Comment: Yeah, their joins are pretty much hard cuts. If you wanted to fade two videos together, you'd have to implement the code that generates the faded frames yourself. It's just an alpha blend, so it's not too hard, but also not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

What codec are you using?

There are two ways to compress video: lossy and lossless.  It's easy to tell them apart. Depending on their length, lossy video files are in the megabyte range, lossless (including uncompressed) are in the gigabyte range.

Here's an oversimplification.  Editing video files is a lot different from editing film, where you just glue the pieces of film together.  It's not just about bitrate, frame rate and resolution.  Most lossy video codecs (MPEG 1-4, Ogg Theora, H.26x, VC-1, etc.) start out with a full frame then record only the changes in movement.  When you watch the video what you're actually seeing is a static scene with layer after layer of changes pasted on top of it.  It looks like you're seeing full frame after full frame, but if you looked at the data in the file all you'd see would be a black background and  scrambled blocks of video.

If it's uncompressed or uses a lossless codec (HuffYUV, Lagarith, FFV1, etc.) then you can edit your video file just like film.  You still have to re-encode the video but it won't effect video quality and you can cut, copy and paste however you like as long as the resolution and frame rate are the same.  If you're video is lossy you have to re-encode it with some loss of video quality, just like saving the same image in JPEG, over and over.

Another option might be to put several pieces of video into a container like MKV and use chapters to have it jump from piece to piece.  I seem to remember being told this is possible but I've never tried it so maybe it isn't.